# How to track kills in World of Warcraft?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I frequently see people saying, for instance, item X dropped after Y kills of mob Z.

What is the simpler way to track how many times you have killed a certain mob in World of Warcraft?

Comment: You do understand that "item X dropped after Y kills of mob Z" doesn't mean anything right?  If an item has a 1% drop rate, you could kill the same creature a million times and it could simply not drop.  Every time you kill that creature there is a 1% chance for that item to drop.  Killing it more or less then a million times does not increase your odd.  So tracking the number of times you kill a creature is pointless useless statistic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have mods for this that keep track of your kills and much more. Here is one to look in to but you have plenty more that might suit you better.

http://www.wowace.com/addons/rarity/

Comment: Rarity fits my needs! Killtracker hasn't been updated in a while I think, I couldn't run it due to Lua script errors.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a Statistics tab under the Achievements screen that tracks overall kills and some Boss monsters.